Transition ending immediately after :hover end


.container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 10vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;

  gap: 1vw;

  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out !important;
}

.container > div {
  background-color: #32363e;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;

  opacity: 0.8;

  padding: 1vw;

  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.container > div:hover > div {
  border: solid yellow 1px;
  visibility: visible !important;
}

.container:has(.proj1:hover) {
  grid-template-columns: 5fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.proj1:hover ~ div > div,
.container:has(.proj1:hover) > div:not(.proj1) > div {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.container:has(.proj2:hover) {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.proj2:hover ~ div > div,
.container:has(.proj2:hover) > div:not(.proj2) > div {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.container:has(.proj3:hover) {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 5fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.proj3:hover ~ div > div,
.container:has(.proj3:hover) > div:not(.proj3) > div {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.container:has(.proj4:hover) {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 5fr 1fr;
}

.proj4:hover ~ div > div,
.container:has(.proj4:hover) > div:not(.proj4) > div {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.container:has(.proj5:hover) {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 5fr;
}

.proj5:hover ~ div > div,
.container:has(.proj5:hover) > div:not(.proj5) > div {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.container > div h1 {
  font-size: small;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}

.container > div p,
.container > div ul,
.container > div h5 {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.container > div:hover p,
.container > div:hover ul,
.container > div:hover h5 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.container > div:hover h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.container > div > div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 1fr 1fr;

  gap: 2vh;
}
<div class="container" id="Projects">
  <div class="proj1">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio error
          vel temporibus pariatur doloribus accusantium nesciunt provident
          minima iure distinctio! Elig
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5>Stack Used:-</h5>

        <ul>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam
          eligendi optio similique commodi qui, corrupti blanditiis laborum non
          eius neque modi, sit laudantium amet, nisi necessitatibus molestiae!
          A, in voluptatibus.
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="proj2">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio error
          vel temporibus pariatur doloribus accusantium nesciunt provident
          minima iure distinctio! Elig
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5>Stack Used:-</h5>

        <ul>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam
          eligendi optio similique commodi qui, corrupti blanditiis laborum non
          eius neque modi, sit laudantium amet, nisi necessitatibus molestiae!
          A, in voluptatibus.
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="proj3">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio error
          vel temporibus pariatur doloribus accusantium nesciunt provident
          minima iure distinctio! Elig
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5>Stack Used:-</h5>

        <ul>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam
          eligendi optio similique commodi qui, corrupti blanditiis laborum non
          eius neque modi, sit laudantium amet, nisi necessitatibus molestiae!
          A, in voluptatibus.
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="proj4">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio error
          vel temporibus pariatur doloribus accusantium nesciunt provident
          minima iure distinctio! Elig
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5>Stack Used:-</h5>

        <ul>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam
          eligendi optio similique commodi qui, corrupti blanditiis laborum non
          eius neque modi, sit laudantium amet, nisi necessitatibus molestiae!
          A, in voluptatibus.
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="proj5">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio error
          vel temporibus pariatur doloribus accusantium nesciunt provident
          minima iure distinctio! Elig
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5>Stack Used:-</h5>

        <ul>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam
          eligendi optio similique commodi qui, corrupti blanditiis laborum non
          eius neque modi, sit laudantium amet, nisi necessitatibus molestiae!
          A, in voluptatibus.
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I have a hover animation on the divs where the parent gird changes column width on hover but the div's do not transition smoothly after hover end.
I tried applying transition property to both parent and the element itself but it still ends abruptly
To view this better: https://portfolio-node-one.vercel.app/
Navigate to Project section from bottom
Edit: The recommended ques answers for why i cant change number of columns/rows for grid and i understood that thats why i have changed size of one column based on hover, but after i hover on another div it abruptly closes the previous hover transition

Please add the HTML to the question with a a minimal reproducible example. CSS without HTML is useless.

I am adding it in snippet, since i have a react components it takes time to convert

The issue seems to be due to how the CSS grid handles the transition of grid-template-columns combined with the visibility and opacity changes. The grid layout can be tricky with transitions, especially when the columns snap back to their original widths.


.container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: auto;
  /* Let the container height adjust based on content */
  display: flex;
  gap: 1vw;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: #32363e;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 1vw;
  flex: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 15vh;
  /* Ensure a minimum height */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* Align content evenly within each div */
}

.container>div:hover {
  flex: 5;
}

.container>div:not(:hover) {
  flex: 0.5;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container>div h1 {
  font-size: small;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}

.container>div p,
.container>div ul,
.container>div h5 {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, visibility 0.3s ease-in-out 0.3s;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.container>div:hover p,
.container>div:hover ul,
.container>div:hover h5 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.container>div:hover h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.container>div>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2vh;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
<div class="container" id="Projects">
  <div class="proj1">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio error vel temporibus pariatur doloribus accusantium nesciunt provident minima iure distinctio! Elig
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5>Stack Used:-</h5>

        <ul>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam eligendi optio similique commodi qui, corrupti blanditiis laborum non eius neque modi, sit laudantium amet, nisi necessitatibus molestiae! A, in voluptatibus.
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="proj2">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio error vel temporibus pariatur doloribus accusantium nesciunt provident minima iure distinctio! Elig
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5>Stack Used:-</h5>

        <ul>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam eligendi optio similique commodi qui, corrupti blanditiis laborum non eius neque modi, sit laudantium amet, nisi necessitatibus molestiae! A, in voluptatibus.
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="proj3">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio error vel temporibus pariatur doloribus accusantium nesciunt provident minima iure distinctio! Elig
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5>Stack Used:-</h5>

        <ul>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam eligendi optio similique commodi qui, corrupti blanditiis laborum non eius neque modi, sit laudantium amet, nisi necessitatibus molestiae! A, in voluptatibus.
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="proj4">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio error vel temporibus pariatur doloribus accusantium nesciunt provident minima iure distinctio! Elig
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5>Stack Used:-</h5>

        <ul>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam eligendi optio similique commodi qui, corrupti blanditiis laborum non eius neque modi, sit laudantium amet, nisi necessitatibus molestiae! A, in voluptatibus.
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="proj5">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio error vel temporibus pariatur doloribus accusantium nesciunt provident minima iure distinctio! Elig
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5>Stack Used:-</h5>

        <ul>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam eligendi optio similique commodi qui, corrupti blanditiis laborum non eius neque modi, sit laudantium amet, nisi necessitatibus molestiae! A, in voluptatibus.
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I guess it should do it.

As you might see, I made some refinements to the CSS, there was some repetitions.
